# Cannot install Jupyter Dashboards

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to install jupyter dashboards from here: https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/dashboards

I installed pip install jupyter_dashboards and restarted and when I open the Notebook, I have the Deploy options in the File menu but I do not have the 'Dashboard view' in the View menu.

See here in the video the problem: http://recordit.co/br6CwoFc6I

How can I activate the dashboard view? Thanks

Comment: Hi aruizga, I've got the same problem, did you somehow manage to solve it? I installed jupyter_bashboard by downloading the zip file ainda using pip install ./dashboard0.4.x